# Exemplo Query Count

Tags: sql-server, query

Alguém teria algum exemplo de como fazer um `COUNT` em uma query, separando os dados por `EstadoId` (como exemplo).

No meu caso eu tenho diversos dados no meu banco, cadastrado por diversos estados, preciso de uma query que realize a contagem.

Quantos dados tem em São Paulo, quantos dados tem em Rio de Janeiro etc...

Fazendo a junção de tudo e vindo os dados

```
SP = 100
RJ = 50
```

E assim sucessivamente para os outros estados.

A variavel que armazena os dados no meu banco é `estadoId`.

Eu uso o SQL Server.

```
Query


  SELECT 
    CASE EstadoId
        WHEN 'FCB48BA3-9507-47F9-91F9-00945D7D29A8' THEN 'Maranhão'
        WHEN 'D5975036-F585-45BF-A8B3-16A598F84FD1' THEN 'Amazonas'
        WHEN 'ED003698-0B2F-4A4D-BFC4-1901B6BB9642' THEN 'Sergipe'
        WHEN 'E15EC502-6F75-4EF8-BF29-2721D7E232C8' THEN 'Piauí'
        WHEN '61F6D4DB-A0D7-4964-B712-27B9B67B3055' THEN 'São Paulo'
        WHEN 'A383B807-CBE2-406F-BCD9-2D5866583EE8' THEN 'Espírito Santo'
        WHEN 'BA11DFC1-2051-44C9-9782-338C439F9AE8' THEN 'Acre'
        WHEN 'C96EE991-7928-46CD-960F-416B7E5A062F' THEN 'Mato Grosso'
        WHEN 'A8F719C2-0C5C-422F-A09B-48E48C000226' THEN 'Rio Grande do Norte'
        WHEN '96F72912-C994-4766-9540-4FE4725D1391' THEN 'Roraima'
        WHEN 'ED4A75AE-9B49-43B0-8187-5813C965C5C2' THEN 'Pará'
        WHEN 'FD7EAB07-34F9-4E07-A18F-6180C3C028DD' THEN 'Distrito Federal'
        WHEN 'F2F3A942-2F3D-4DDD-80B3-71E2276B0223' THEN 'Mato Grosso do Sul'
        WHEN '1C50585F-5293-499E-91DE-7952927273C7' THEN 'Rio Grande do Sul'
        WHEN '49AF6EA6-A6B9-4647-8586-7D3D22AC4109' THEN 'Goiás'
        WHEN '6607DD2D-3A24-4ED0-8C54-886139046FFA' THEN 'Ceará'
        WHEN '06745B93-AB09-4865-9157-8A246A1E0F05' THEN 'Tocantins'
        WHEN '3DBAA189-DD6E-4FB4-868E-96CFCBC8D515' THEN 'Santa Catarina'
        WHEN '67F4E360-CDE7-4437-8AAF-9846A3470870' THEN 'Paraná'
        WHEN '1A094EB4-384C-40D1-A254-B4F5F18102B5' THEN 'Amapá'
        WHEN '1F8F07B3-0471-4791-AF20-C61E7DE51587' THEN 'Paraíba'
        WHEN 'B0B9E3E2-DA65-40C4-B001-C756B196D557' THEN 'Rondônia'
        WHEN '9982FA1A-47FB-4042-B8D9-C9F06F116AD9' THEN 'Alagoas'
        WHEN '8852C8D8-F088-406F-B929-DEEB59983C66' THEN 'Minas Gerais'
        WHEN '79F036B0-BC15-4D70-B62A-E60D6437134B' THEN 'Bahia'
        WHEN '058AAF5A-3847-4825-8AE2-E7B4E3BEA5AC' THEN 'Rio de Janeiro'
        WHEN '22BE3B04-1970-417F-A994-F8BB90DCB2F1' THEN 'Pernambuco'
    END AS Title, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM jud_Processos
WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1 AND EstadoId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EstadoId
ORDER BY EstadoId
```

Comment: Exemplo:

select count(nome) from Produtos;
> 198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar o seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    estadoId char(02),
    valor int 
)

INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('SP', 1)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('SP', 2)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('SP', 3)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('RJ', 1)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('RJ', 2)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('XX', 1)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('XX', 3)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('XX', 3)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('XX', 3)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('XX', 3)

SELECT ISNULL(estadoID, ' Total'), COUNT(1)
  FROM temp
 GROUP BY estadoID WITH ROLLUP  
 ORDER BY 1
```

Isto irá gerar o seguinte output.

```
estadoID       NumeroRegistos
RJ             2 
SP             3 
XX             5 
 Total         10
```

Outra alternativa, ao invés de listar o Estado em linhas diferentes, apresenta o Estado como coluna

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT',' + QUOTENAME(c.estadoId) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM
            (
                SELECT estadoId, valor
                  FROM temp
           ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
                 COUNT(valor)
                 FOR estadoID IN(' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

O resultado será:

```
RJ  SP  XX 
2   3   5
```

Comment: Fiz umas modificações na query mais funcionou era isto mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: tira uma duvida, nesta mesma query é possivel fazer um count geral?

Comment: eu tive que usar um case na query pois como estou puxando por EstadoId, tive que fazer a conversão do Id para o nome que vale aquele id poderia dar uma olhada na minha query e ver se é possivel adicionar um total, irei atualizar o topico

Comment: acabei de atualizar o topico

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo, para obter um total, basta substituir o GROUP BY EstadoId por GROUP BY EstadoId WITH ROLLUP (tal como no meu exemplo)

Comment: ha sim, desculpa eu tinha usado porem não tinha visto o valor vindo no grafico! agora esta correto, obrigado novamente!